# Prove $C[a,b],d_\infty$ is complete.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I have this problem with this exercise.

> **Prove $(C[a,b],d_\infty)$ is complete.**

I don't have a very clear idea of how to prove this. But I start to attack the problem in this way:

Let $\{f_n\}$ a Cauchy sequence in $d_\infty$.Then given a $\epsilon >0$ exists a  $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n,m>N$ then $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<\epsilon \ \ \forall x\in [a,b]$.

*I'm stuck here, can someone help me?* I will be grateful.

Comment: The problem is just asking you to prove that the (pointwise) limit of a series of continuous functions is also continuous, which follows from standard uniform convergence arguments and the fact that $[a,b]$ is compact.

Comment: @anomaly Can yo be more specific? I don't follow your idea...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for every $x$, $(f_n(x))$ is a Cauchy sequence, call $f(x)$ its limit. Show that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly towards $f$, this implies that $f$ is continuous.